# Can a 동사 take 냐고?

Tags: grammar

Why does 먹다 take 냐고 instead of 느냐고 in the sentence (according to the Korean University Korean Dictionary)

> 그는 선미에게 아직도 회를 안 먹냐고 물으며 웃었다.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, (action) verbs officially take -느냐고 and adjectives take -냐고; however unofficially, they both can take -냐고. See [Quoting Different Endings: ~자고, ~(으/느)냐고](https://www.howtostudykorean.com/unit-3-intermediate-korean-grammar/unit-3-lessons-51-58/lesson-53/) for a more in-depth explanation.

Comment: How it is possible to make it to the dictionary if it unofficial as you said?

Comment: I probably should have said "colloquial" or "informal" and dictionaries do have example sentences of each of those.

Answer (score 2):

I've been speaking Korean for ~40 years, and 먹냐(고) being wrong is news to me.  Trust me, no Korean living in 2017 will have an issue with "아직도 회 안 먹냐?"

"아직도 회를 안 먹(느)냐고 물었다" is fine both with or without "느", although I think "먹냐고" is more commonly used.

In fact, ending a sentence with -느냐 is really old-fashioned.  If you say "아직도 회 안 먹느냐?", most Koreans would wonder why you're talking like some old man in folk tales.

- And, yes, there are some prescriptivists who have the gall to tell *all* Koreans how *everybody* is using our own language wrong except for themselves.  If you are a language learner, I guess sometimes it can be confusing.  Hopefully you could find a good textbook that tries to give a balanced account, not some obsolete version of Korean dreamed up by old scholars.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable input to the question.

Answer (score 0):

"I don't know about the rule.. but in real life, you can always omit '느' from '느냐고'. (of course not backward)" <-- **it's wrong information. sorry.**

---

after 동사, you should use '-느냐'
after 형용사, you should use '-(으)냐'
thus '먹냐' is **incorrect** word. (but people in real life doesn't matter, actually.)

However, after 동사 + '-**으시**-' '-**었**-' '-**겠**-', you can use either '느냐' or '냐'

Here are some examples.

> [case of 동사 + '-었-'] (싸웠다 = 싸우 + 었 + 다)
>   "왜 싸웠냐고 묻잖아!"
>   "왜 싸웠느냐고 묻잖아!"
>
> [case of '-었-'] (했다 = 하 + 었 + 다)
>   "그녀는 왜 그런 일을 했냐고 물었다"
>   "그녀는 왜 그런 일을 했느냐고 물었다"
>
> [case of 동사 + '-겠-']
>   "얼마나 외로웠겠느냐"
>    "얼마나 외로웠겠냐"
>
> [case of 동사 + '-으시-' or '-겠-'] (싶으셨 = 싶+ 으시 + 었)
>   "너를 두고 떠나고 싶으셨겠느냐"
>   "너를 두고 떠나고 싶으셨겠냐"

---

just for notice, this is the origin of -냐고 and -느냐고.
~느냐? + ~라고 = ~느냐고
~냐? + ~라고 = ~냐고

-느냐?(-냐?) is '의문형 문장종결어미(interrogative final endings)'.

-라고 means that the sentence before -라고 is quoted.

> Mother told me that she lied to me
>   엄마가 나에게 거짓말을 했다**고** 말했어

this is why -느냐고(-냐고) is deeply related to those final endings -느냐(-냐).
   on the other hand, -고 is not that important. because you can simply change the ending -느냐?(-냐?) into -느냐고(-냐고).

> 할아버지가 얼마나 외로웠겠**느냐?**
>   형은 할아버지가 얼마나 외로웠겠**느냐고** 말했다.

---

Reference :

> “그쪽은 날 언제 봤다고 꼬박꼬박 말꼬리를 잘라 먹냐.” 이처럼 구어체에서는 ‘먹느냐’ 대신 ‘먹냐’를 많이 쓴다. 이 경우
>   글쓴이도 ‘먹냐’가 ‘먹느냐’보다 좀 더 자연스럽게 느껴진다. 하지만 현행 문법 규정으로 보면 **‘먹냐’는 바른말이 아니다.**
>
> ‘느냐’와 ‘냐’는 그 구분이 모호해 흔히 혼용해 쓴다. 하지만 글을 쓸 땐 이들을 구분해야 한다. ‘표준국어대사전’은
>   ‘느냐’를 ‘있다’ ‘없다’ ‘계시다’의 어간이나 동사 어간 뒤에 붙여 쓴다고 규정하고 있다. 따라서 “지금 무엇을 먹느냐?”
>   “안에 누가 있느냐?” 따위로 써야 한다.
>
> .....
>
> 동사 뒤에는 ‘느냐’, 형용사 뒤에는 ‘(으)냐’를 써야 한다. 그런데 ‘느냐’와 ‘냐’ 중 아무것이나 써도 무방할 때가 있다. 바로 ‘-으시-’ ‘-었-’ ‘-겠-’ 뒤에 붙을 경우이다.
>
> .....
>
> Original Link: 
>   http://news.khan.co.kr/kh_news/khan_art_view.html?artid=201303202148265&code=990100#csidx88cc46d66a13bfd9946f6ef88f0634c

Comment: So you are saying that 냐고 can also be attached to a 동사 with a slight difference in the meaning. I would really like to know more about this.

Comment: @HusainAbdali sorry. that was completely wrong information. I just edited in detail.